# Convert function to its harmonic in mathematica

Tags: functions

How do I expand the following function function:
(x0 + B Cos[x] + A Sin[x])^3

such that the function expand as a harmonic that id I get Sin(x), Sin(2x), Sin(3x) and similarly Cos terms...Instead of (sinx)^3 and (cosx)^3 terms.

I tried using trigreduce but still all terms are not in the form of x,2x and 2x...I still have terms which are quadratic and cubic in sin and cos.

Please help!

Comment: This question is poorly written. It does neither use correct syntax nor explain what the goal is.

Comment: Please update your question with some actual Wolfram Language code! And add more detail - "both are not working" doesn't help us help you at all.

Answer (score 1):

If I guess your question right, the function you're looking for is `TrigReduce`

Try

```
x = (x0 + A Sin[ω t] + B Cos[ω t])^3
Collect[TrigReduce[x], {Sin[ _], Cos[ _]}]
(*1/4 (6 A^2 x0 + 6 B^2 x0 + 4 x0^3) + 
1/4 (3 A^2 B + 3 B^3 + 12 B x0^2) Cos[t \[Omega]] + 
1/4 (-6 A^2 x0 + 6 B^2 x0) Cos[2 t \[Omega]] + 
1/4 (-3 A^2 B + B^3) Cos[3 t \[Omega]] + 
1/4 (3 A^3 + 3 A B^2 + 12 A x0^2) Sin[t \[Omega]] + 
3 A B x0 Sin[2 t \[Omega]] + 1/4 (-A^3 + 3 A B^2) Sin[3 t \[Omega]]*)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply...

Comment: By this the answer comes: 1/4 (6 A^2 x0 + 4 x0^3 + 6 A^2 BCos[\[Omega]t] + 
   12 x0^2 BCos[\[Omega]t] + 12 x0 BCos[\[Omega]t]^2 + 
   4 BCos[\[Omega]t]^3 - 6 A^2 x0 Cos[2 \[Omega]t] - 
   6 A^2 BCos[\[Omega]t] Cos[2 \[Omega]t] + 3 A^3 Sin[\[Omega]t] + 
   12 A x0^2 Sin[\[Omega]t] + 
   24 A x0 BCos[\[Omega]t] Sin[\[Omega]t] + 
   12 A BCos[\[Omega]t]^2 Sin[\[Omega]t] - A^3 Sin[3 \[Omega]t])

Comment: It still has Cos square and Cos 3 terms

Comment: Is it possible to further simplify it...like completely remoce the quadratic and cubic in cos terms

Comment: It worked...Thanks a lot:)

Comment: @Nishta You're welcome. See my modified answer